# Setting priority for services at start up?

Tags: windows-xp, services

Is there any way to set priority for services at start up?  I want my local area network to start before other network-related services.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there is no such thing as "priority" because it is based on "dependency".

Let's say we have three services A, B, and X. A and B are dependent on X.

X will start first, and when it is done starting A and B will be started later. Note that this means A and B cannot be started without X already started. Also be aware that Windows does not guarantee the order in which A and B will be started (if you need to guarantee order, create a dependency between them).